# Random number game with two classes, not iterating. suggestions?

Tags: class, loops, project

One of my professors has given us a project of creating a random number guessing game. The requirements for the game is that it have at least one public property and one public method, and then the actual rules of the loop. The game must also consist of at least two classes. I will list my existing code in hopes that somebody can guide me in the right direction. When it runs, it runs only the console.writeline message about the rules. It then stops. The loop does not iterate, and the "method" I placed in my non-test class. I've been struggling with this class since the beginning as I have no previous experience in programming. Most of the examples I have seen of this game involve only ONE class. So I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to put in the other one, or how to separate them into two classes and which of the code goes where.

My code goes as follows, with the non-test class first.

```
using System;

namespace numbergame
{
class mysteryNumber
{
    public int myRand {get; set;}
    public int playerGuess { get; set; }

    public void DisplayMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The most important rule of the Number Guessing Game is that \nyou can't talk about the Number Guessing Game."); 
    }
```

The next bit of code is where I have most of my code and the main method.

```
using System;

namespace numbergame
{
    class mysteryNumberTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int myRand;
            int guessCounter = 1;
            int playerGuess = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("The number you must choose is a number between \n1 and 100. Your attempts remaining will be \nshown upon incorrect guess. The number of attempts it took you will be\n shown upon correct guess.");


            Random randomNumbers = new Random();
            myRand = randomNumbers.Next(1, 100);

            {
                while (guessCounter < 5) ;
                Console.WriteLine("Feeling lucky, punk? Guess your number: ");
                playerGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                {
                    if (playerGuess == myRand)
                        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You're a real winner!\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("The number of attempts it took you was: {0}", guessCounter);
                    {
                        guessCounter = guessCounter + 10; }
                        if (playerGuess != myRand)
                        { guessCounter += 1; }
                        Console.WriteLine("No. You have made {1} attempts.\nYou have {2} attempts left.", guessCounter, (5 - guessCounter));
                    if (guessCounter >= 6)
                        Console.WriteLine("The number of guesses was exceeded.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The instance variables and automated properties in the first non-test class seem as though they serve no purpose. The method DisplayMessage() also seems like it may not actually function.

But I have no clue. I'm not sure why my loop isn't beginning, and when it does begin, I have a feeling my guessCounter may not increment the way I want it to because I had this problem with last week's exercise.

Any help is appreciated. :(

Comment: Your code seems to have a lot of needless anonymous-scopes in-use, as though it belongs to control statements that have been moved-around, such as your `while (guessCounter < 5);` statement (which doesn't actually do anything). I suggest you read-through your code carefully yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some {}'s it would appear.

it goes

```
while (test) 
{ // <- Notice the bracket
//Code to repeat 5 times goes here.
} // <- it closes
```

Also: If you're wanting it to repeat  5 times, initialize guessCounter to 0.

Comment: There's also a few other things wrong I can see. Learn how to use loops and conditionals, and stop coming to StackOverflow to do your homework for you. At least google it first.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, as Dai said, there's a lot of anonymous scope that you just don't need.

Now let's see what your teacher asked. He wants 2 classes. 1 Public property, 1 public method. My guess would be that the public method verify if the number entered is valid?

Also, a *while* loop is declared as follows:

```
while(bCondition == true)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Notice how you declare your loop as *while(guessCounter < 5);* (notice end of instruction). This is why it doesn't "enter" the loop.

Now, something like this would work better:

```
while(numberGuesses < 5)
{
    // We've entered the loop. 
    // We now want to know if the guess is good. If it is, tell the player then leave
    // the loop
    if(playerGuess == yourNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You guessed it right! Right after {0} guesses!", numberGuesses); 
        break; // Break leaves the loop it is in. Therefore our 'while'.
    }

    // No need for else instruction since you can't be here with the good guess
    // do what you must do here when he got it wrong

}
```

As for your public method and property, can't really help you there, because I do not see why he would want 2 classes in total. However, consider doing this:

```
anyNumber++; // correspond to : anyNumber = anyNumber + 1; 
// or
anyNumber += aNumber; // where a number can be any number. (anyNumber = anyNumber + aNumber)
```

So you could do numberGuesses++; at the end of the loop. As for the rest, I would assume you should try and draw on a paper sheet how you would see it, or your teacher would.

Answer (score 0):

I would create your secondary class with a READ ONLY PROPERTY that gets  initialized with a random number in the contructor.  Something like this:

```
public class Mystery
{

    private static Random R = new Random();

    private int _number;
    public int Number 
    {
        get { return _number; }
    }

    public Mystery()
    {
        _number = R.Next(1, 101); // 1 to 100 INCLUSIVE
    }

    public void DisplayMessage()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The most important rule of the Number Guessing Game is that \nyou can't talk about the Number Guessing Game.");
        Console.WriteLine("The number you must choose is a number between \n1 and 100. Your attempts remaining will be \nshown upon incorrect guess. The number of attempts it took you will be\n shown upon correct guess.");
    }

}
```

Note that if you want a number between 1 and 100 INCLUSIVE, then the second parameter to Random.Next() should be 101, not 100.

Now you can create an instance of this class in Main() and use it like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int guessCounter = 1;
        int playerGuess = 0;

        Mystery mystery = new Mystery();
        mystery.DisplayMessage();

        while (guessCounter < 5) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Feeling lucky, punk? Guess your number: ");
            playerGuess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (playerGuess == mystery.Number)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You're a real winner!\n");
                Console.WriteLine("The number of attempts it took you was: {0}", guessCounter);
            }
            else
            {
                // ... do something else in here ...                    
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't quite follow the rules for when the guess is incorrect.  In one place you're adding 10, while in another you're adding 1.  I'll let you figure out the "... do something else in here ..." part.